# IronPython adding namespace to scope in C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have following C# code

```
namespace API
{
    public class AutoRcu
    {
        private ...

        public AutoRcu() 
        {
            ...
        }

        public void pressKey(string name)
        {
            ...
        }
    ...
}
```

I am running following IronPython code to operate C# code.

```
rcu.pressKey("Menu")
```

Ths works fine but the question is:
I would like to change Python API to run:

```
API.rcu.pressKey()
```

instead of

```
rcu.pressKey()
```

How to do that?

Now I add such a class by using

```
pyScope.SetVariable("rcu",AutoRcu)
```

function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're essentially creating an object that has a property `rcu` that is an instance of your `AutoRcu` class.  Just create the object.

```
dynamic api = new ExpandoObject();
api.rcu = new AutoRcu();
pyScope.SetVariable("API", api);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine.